# How to disable particular layout or separator in list view row in onitem click in android

Tags: android

I have added a separator for a list view for giving background for linearlayout in row.xml. I have implemented onitem click for a list view row. I am displaying a dialog for onitemclick for list view Row. If the user clicks that layout background or separator Onitem click is triggering. How do I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: @Blaine Anderson I shouldn't post the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disable the click listener for layout